# onClick isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to create a tic tac toe game in react. Right now I'm at the beginning and I'm not trying to add logic to it right now. I'm trying to have a onclick function on my box component so it can read that I clicked on the grid component using console.log. but im getting errors in my onclick function. Also, do you think I need handle event to make it work?
here is my code:

```
export default App;

class ApplicationComponent extends React.Component {

   clicked(event){

        console.log(event.target)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Application Component</div>
        );
    }
    resetBoard(){
        console.log("what up world");
    }
    checkingWon(){
        console.log("what up world 2")
    }
}
class GridComponent extends React.Component {
onGreet(){
    console.log("grid")
}
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="grid">
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
                <BoxComponent/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class BoxComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="box" onClick={(BoxComponent)=>
                this.click.bind(this.onGreet)}>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: A working, minimal example would be helpful. Use codesandbox to present your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`BoxComponent` does not have a `onGreet` method. If you want `BoxComponent` to call `GridComponent`'s `onGreet` method, you need to pass that function as a prop to its children:

```
class GridComponent extends React.Component {
  onGreet(){
    console.log("grid")
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
        <BoxComponent onClick={this.onGreet}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

}

Then, call that prop form the child:

```
class BoxComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {onClick} = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="box" onClick={onClick}>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: don't I need to bind the two components together?

Comment: Yes but I'm not seeing anything in my console.log when i click the BoxComponent